# Why is Axios not using the Content-Type header and converting the request method to GET when PATCHing to a specific URL?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have inherited a codebase using Axios, and I am otherwise unfamiliar with the library. This is a Node application, and I'm attempting to send a PATCH request to a third party API. Axios is configured using the following:

```
const axios = require('axios').create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  },
  auth: {
    username: process.env.API_USER,
    password: process.env.API_PW,
  },
});
```

I then try to make the following PATCH request:

```
const data = {
    fields: {
      field_a: 'yes',
      field_b: 'no',    
    },
  };

  try {
    const res = await axios.patch(`/user/${user.id}`, data, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    return res;
  } catch (err){
    console.error(err);
  }
```

From what I can see I'm just redefining the Content-Type header when making the patch call, but that was just an attempt to figure this out. It doesn't work either way. What I see in the response object's config property is the following (most of it is excluded):

```
{
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json"
    User-Agent: "axios/0.19.0"
  },
  method: 'patch',
}
```

Looking at the request property of the same response object I see that the method there is listed as "GET" with the Content-Type header also not listed there. It appears as though the Content-Type header is being stripped and the method is being changed to GET.

If I change nothing but the URL destination to `/userWRONGPATH/${user.id}` I receive, as expected, a 404 response, but the response object's config data includes this:

```
{
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json"
    Content-Length: 105
    Content-Type: "application/json"
    User-Agent: "axios/0.19.0"
  }
}
```

The response object's request method is now the expected 'PATCH'. I am unsure why the patch method would work for other paths if that is in fact what is happening here.

Comment: Sounds to me like the backend is probably doing a 302 or 303 redirect, which changes your request to a GET (at least, it does for POST request, I'd assume it does for this as well).

Comment: That does sound like a reasonable possibility. Thank you. I'm reaching out to the API developers to get more information.

Comment: I'd just hit the same endpoint with curl and see if it gives you a redirect

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and you are correct. The issue was that without a trailing slash the API redirects the request, but unfortunately the redirect was changing the request method. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think that the problem could be related of send the header again in Axios you define a config and that is added to all the requests.

This is an example that I use to order the project with axios.

```
// Axios custom config
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: urlBase,
  // timeout: 1000,
  headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
});


export const apiPatchRequest = (url, id, obj) => (
  axiosInstance.patch(`${url}/${id}`, obj)
);
```

Comment: Hey thanks. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the issue. I've tried with and without redefining the Content-Type header without any change in result.